# Drag with three fingers missing in OS X 10.11 Beta "El Capitan" (15A215h)

Tags: macos, gesture

I decided to try out the El Capitan Public Beta for fun by putting it on my external drive and booting off of it. However, one of the first things I've noticed is that the drag gesture in System Preferences->Trackpad is not to be found. Is this normal? I don't know what Beta version I'm running (a web search of the build number turns nothing up about the Beta version), I do know it was the current version about a month ago, anyway the build number is 15A215h. Having to press and drag the old fashioned way seems awful, especially after using the three finger drag.

Is the drag gesture present in newer Beta versions? If not, is there somehow that I can enable again (maybe with a Terminal command)?

Comment: Check for software updates. If it says you're up to date, you're on Public Beta 5.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, send feedback to Apple using Feedback Assistant. Even if you manage to get your issue solved, there's a decent chance other people have it too. Tell Apple that their beta software has a problem!

Comment: @user24601 Great ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drag gesture has migrated. It is now present in the Accessibility Preferences, Mouse & Trackpad, under `Trackpad Options...`

[image: Screenshot of System Preferences Accessibility panel]

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help. Still, that seems like a very strange place for that preference to be, I will definitely use Feedback Assistant to report it, but thanks just the same.

Comment: I agree, it's a strange place.